# OpenID и разные домены

Tags: php, openid

Использую подобную библиотеку (https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication) пытаюсь сделать авторизацию, но не простую.

Авторизация через один домен работает отлично, но возможно ли сделать так, чтобы авторизировались мы через один домен, а авторизация работала на другом? (оба домены мои, просто в этом есть необходимость)

Данный после авторизации с одного домена при редиректе переходят на другой, но проверку они, как я понял, не проходят из-за разница возвращающего адреса и нового после редиректа.

Вопрос в том, возможно ли это вообще и если да, то хотя бы примерно как?

Comment: Ни у кого нет идей?